# JSF 1.2 AJAX Redirect to URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

I've got a requirement where we need to redirect to a page for JSF 1.2 Ajax call. In our case, we need to redirect to session expired page when the ajax call get fired after the session got expired. We are implementing the session expiry check in a filter and the invocation of httpservletresponse.sendRedirect is redirecting correctly to the session expired page as expected, but the url is not getting changed which is the issue now.

Any hints/soultion either at the client/server side is highly appreciated.

~Ragesh

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to find a solution for the above problem.

In the filter, I set the response header **"Location"** and another custom header which I'll use in the client side to filter the response.

**Filter code:**

```
httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
httpServletResponse.setHeader("x-timeout-status", "true");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", httpServletResponse
                            .encodeRedirectURL(sessionexpiryurl));
```

Richfaces have got a javascript file with various callbacks required during the AJAX call invocation which is packed inside the Richfaces libraries. There is one callback function called "**processResponse**" which will get invoked upon receiving response for all AJAX call initiated by JSF Ajax components . I've made use of this to handle the redirection functionality.

**JS code:**

```
var originalAjaxProcessResponse = A4J.AJAX.processResponse;

A4J.AJAX.processResponse = function(req) {
    if (req.getResponseHeader('x-timeout-Status') != undefined && req.getResponseHeader('x-timeout-status') == 'true') {
        window.location.href = req.getResponseHeader('Location');
    } else {
        originalAjaxProcessResponse(req);
    }   
}
```

Here we are overriding the method to handle our specific case and delegate the rest of the ajax call response handling to the in-built  processing provided by richfaces.

Please let me know if you see any limitation to this solution or have a better solution to this problem

~Ragesh